# Any real contribution of functional analysis to quantum theory as a branch of physics?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, ho.history-overview, quantum-mechanics

In the last paragraph of [this last paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06630) of Klaas Landsman, you can read:

> Finally, let me note that this was a winner's (or "whig") history, full of hero-worship: following in the footsteps of Hilbert, von Neumann established the link between quantum theory and functional analysis that has lasted. Moreover, partly through von Neumann's own contributions (which are on a par with those of Bohr, Einstein, and Schrodinger), the precision that functional analysis has brought to quantum theory has greatly benefited the foundational debate. However, it is simultaneously a loser's history: starting with Dirac and continuing with Feynman, until the present day physicists have managed to bring quantum theory forward in utter (and, in my view, arrogant) disregard for the relevant mathematical literature. As such, **functional analysis has so far failed to make any real contribution to quantum theory as a branch of physics** (as opposed to mathematics), and in this respect its role seems to have been limited to something like classical music or other parts of human culture that adorn life but do not change the economy or save the planet. On the other hand, like General Relativity, perhaps the intellectual development reviewed
>   in this paper is one of those human achievements that make the planet worth saving.

To balance this interesting debate, if there actually exists real reasons to disagree with above bolded sentence of Klaas Landsman, let me ask the following:

What are the real contributions of functional analysis to quantum theory as a branch of physics?

Here "real" should be understood in the sense underlying the above paragraph.

This question was asked [on physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514572/26397) and [on PhysicsOverflow](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/42635).

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mean real contributions to quantum physics beyond those of von Neumann? Are you alluding to quantum field theory? Otherwise, for what concerns the explanation of atoms and molecules, functional analysis and quantum mechanics are essentially the same thing. Rightly seen from two different perspective (math vs physics).

Comment: I agree with the entire quote, not just the bolded part.

Comment: I am not sure i understand the term "real" contribution. Do you mean some development in QM which has been dictated by some result of functional analysis (instead of some demand imposed by experimental data or physical arguments)?

Comment: Or would you even be interested in insights in the understanding of QM which are supported by the mathematical properties and methods ?

Comment: I've voted to close as "opinion-based". I agree with Konstantinos Kanakoglou that "real" is an opinion-based, or at least unclear, word here.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43519/711/

Comment: One important branch of functional analysis is the theory of integral equations. And integral equations appear in quantum scattering theory. Another example is the integral quantum hall effect, where the hall conductivity is identified with a Fredholm index.

Comment: I do not agree closing. There is a well-established notion  of what *real physics* is (e. g. "something for which physics Nobel prize can be awarded" or "predicting or explaining experimentally observable phenomena") as well as some common notion of what a *real contribution of functional analysis* would be. At least, "realness" defines a rather obvious order in both aspects, and hence this question is as good as asking for the strongest known version of a theorem. I would very much like to see answers of the form "a (non-trivial) theorem A informed prediction of phenomenon B", if possible.

Comment: ... most of answers so far are rather weak in this sense, they are advanced versions of "look, you don't need maths IRL but it's helps you to learn to organize your thoughts" cocktail party Maths apology. Closing the question that has chances to get real answers is a pity.

Comment: @Kostya_I Theorems don't make predictions - models do. The hard part about building mathematical models is choosing the right definitions, e.g. Einstein metrics on manifolds or Lie group representations on Hilbert spaces - this is what you need to do calculations.  If those calculations consistently agree with experiment then the model is accepted - nobody outside of mathematics could care less whether they are properly justified by theorems.  Clarifying and validating definitions (with theorems!) is the primary purpose of mathematical work - that's a boast, not an apology.

Comment: @PaulSiegel, examples of theorems that do make predictions are abundant. Wigner's *theorem* on classification of representations of Poincaré group was proven with the purpose of classifying particles one can expect to discover. The behavior of Fermi-Pasta-Ulam chain was a complete mystery before KAM *theorem* came along. Spin-statistics *theorem*... Index *theorem*... Also, many *theorems* just underscore and organize general features of *calculations*, so I do not agree with your countraposing the two.

Comment: ... concretely, though, there *does exist* a sentiment among some physicists (explicitly stated in textbooks) that making QM rigorous does not pay off in terms of physical understanding. You may just look for solutions to stationary Schroedinger equation; if your potential is reasonable, they are either exploding at infinity (unphysical), or bounded but don't go to zero (continuous spectrum), or they go to zero (discrete spectrum). Who needs the general definition of the spectrum of an unbounded operator in a Hilbert space? Would be nice to see concrete examples proving that wrong.

Comment: @Kostya_I Other than maybe Fermi-Pasta, of which I don’t know enough to tell, I believe your examples are actually *post*-dictions of the exact kind pragmatists (not me!) might (and apparently sometimes [*did*](//mathoverflow.net/a/13980)) dismiss as “cocktail party apology”. That is why I prefer the longer-term view of math’s role reflected in Paul’s answer (or my [examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348126/any-real-contribution-of-functional-analysis-to-quantum-theory-as-a-branch-of-ph#comment872052_348156), to which one might add Fourier analysis, Clifford algebra,...)

Comment: @Kostya_I Let's take your first example. What does Wigner's theorem predict? Hopefully not the existence of a fundamental particle for every projective irrep of the Poincare group, because there is one of the latter for every positive real mass. The theorem does something better: it shows how to define particles as representation theoretic objects, yielding a framework for doing calculations which make predictions. I'm not making the strawman argument that theorems aren't important to physicists, just that their real purpose is to provide good definitions.

Comment: @PaulSiegel : I mostly agree with you, but perhaps you're overstating the case a bit. Consider general relativity. Certainly, Einstein's work in creating the model was the most important step. But there are enough mathematical difficulties that finding solutions to the equations is a hugely important task in its own right. This seems to be a case where mathematical theorems ("such-and-such is a solution to the equations of general relativity") lead directly to predictions.

Comment: @PaulSiegel, I think you answered your own question: if you insist on defining particles as representation theoretical object (as opposed to "something that leaves traces in a cloud chamber"), you are thereby making a prediction (that the irrep of the Poincare group is all that matters). Wigner's theorem then sharpens that to a prediction that mass and spin/helicity is all that matters.

Comment: I actually don't disagree with you. But compare two questions: "what did representation theory contribute to real physics" and similar for FA. While you may answer "definitions" to the first question, a physicist would likely rather say "selection rules, 3j symbols etc." It is not clear (to me) whether FA affected physicist's toolbox in a similar (or any) way - Schroedinger and hordes of undergraduates lived rather happily without the right definitions. I'm not saying yours is not a valid answer, just that it sounds less convincing (to me) than a more concrete one would.

Comment: Random matrix theory is used in QM a lot, and is apparently now affected quite a bit by free probability, which came out of functional analysis.  Maybe that's too indirect though.

Answer (score 50):

I'm can't claim to have studied the relevant history in a lot of detail, but count me a skeptic of Landsman's claim.  Let's take this [little paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.13.508) and the [companion](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f368/f95a533c910cb3ef71c8f4aa45df22a31168.pdf) that it cites as a test case, which I hope we can all agree is "real physics".  The authors are clearly well versed in the calculus of variations and the representation theory of Lie groups.  Both of these subjects are heavily intertwined with functional analysis - functional analysis is even foundational for the former.  Are we to believe that these physicists were entirely ignorant of the subject?  Or is the argument that functional analysis only influenced them indirectly through its contact with those mathematical applications?

I think Landsman's argument makes an error common among pure mathematicians about how mathematics is actually applied to the sciences.  We tend to think about theorems, because those are the main objects of study in our work, but for consumers of mathematics it is the definitions that are important.  The role of theorems is to validate the correctness and importance of definitions, and sometimes provide tools for manipulating them.  The *definitions* of functional analysis - (un)bounded linear operators, Hilbert spaces, states, and so on - appear all over the place in quantum mechanics.  And many of the big open problems in theoretical physics call primarily for definitions rather than theorems: Is there a measure space on which path integrals make sense?  What is the correct notion of Dirac operator on the loop space of a manifold?  Is there a gauge theory which includes both gravity and the standard model?  And so on.

Comment: I agree with the importance of definitions. For a recent example see this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07895 by Binder and Rychkov where they establish some theorems but perhaps more importantly give definitions of QFT models with $N$ component valued fields even if $N$ is not a positive integer. BTW the big open problem "Is there a measure spece on which path integrals make sense" has a solution: for Euclidean path integrals on flat space, the measure space is the space of temperate distributions $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: +1 for the first two sentences of the second paragraph alone.

Comment: Well - theorems are important too, say, the residue theorem. But I agree, the relative importance of definitions vs. theorems is usually underestimated. Language guides patterns of thinking.

Comment: This is getting a lot of upvotes, but I’m not sure I agree. The number of physicists who could tell you what a bounded operator is, much less the right definition of the spectrum (which I just had to look up) is a small fraction of the whole in my experience. Most physicists are at least a sloppy with definitions as they are with theorems. Most of the time, for whatever reason, it just doesn’t seem to matter, and the mathematicians can clean everything up later (at least with QM — we haven’t been so lucky with QFT).

Comment: @AaronBergman I think his point is that math provides a toolbox of concepts that have already been stress-tested. Only *then* can others afford to use them more sloppily.

Comment: @AaronBergman - a  propos, true story: Physicist as Dean's Rep in a math oral final asks for difference between spectrum and eigenvalues. Crickets ...

Comment: The fact that lots of physicists are confused by the notion of the spectrum in functional analysis stems from the fact that most of them took at least one quantum mechanics course in which the spectrum of a linear operator on Hilbert space was defined  (probably correctly, at least in context).  That physics professors and textbook authors view this formalism as a foundational topic in the field - and thus most physicists are _even aware of its existence_ - is in my mind evidence of the influence of functional analysis.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler For better or for worse, it’s exactly the other way around. Physicists used (and use) these concepts well before they have been stress-tested from a mathematics point of view. The math has almost always, to my knowledge, come later. As I said, it’s somewhat impressive that this hasn’t led to more problems.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I would be very impressed if you could find any quantum mechanics book, either undergraduate or graduate, that contains the correct definition of the spectrum outside of a finite dimensional space.

Comment: @AaronBergman In my undergraduate QM class we used "An Introduction to Quantum Theory" by Hannabuss, who writes on page 75: "Given a self-adjoint operator, $A$, in an infinite-dimensional space, it is useful to define its _spectrum_ to be the set of complex numbers $\alpha$ for which $A - \alpha$ is not invertible.  (The notion of invertible is not quite straightforward either, but our discussion will not be sensitive to the precise details.)"  Now this book is in the "Oxford Graduate Texts in Mathematics" series, but my class was in the physics department, so maybe it's a push.

Comment: @AaronBergman We may be talking past each other. Sure the envelope may need pushed into the not-yet stress-tested, as with unbounded operators or  infinite-dimensional representations, but it’s (almost always?) there to begin with. Apollonius’ conics, Lagrange and Gauss’ divergence theorem, Riemann and Ricci/Levi-Civita’s geometry, Hilbert’s spectra, Sturm and Liouville’s eigenfunctions, Frobenius’ representations, Cartan’s spinors, etc., were there for the taking by Kepler, Maxwell, Einstein, Born et al., Schrödinger, Wigner, Pauli, etc. (I’d call path integrals or string theory atypical.)

Comment: Perhaps a good example to consider is general relativity. In [Einstein the Stubborn](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4305), Galina Weinstein makes the case that the rigorous mathematics of Levi-Civita and Hilbert played a crucial role in correcting an error in Einstein's development of the theory. If we accept Weinstein's narrative, it supports Francois Ziegler's point and goes against Aaron Bergman's claim that problems don't arise when physicists just barrel forward with non-rigorous arguments. (Though maybe some will argue that Einstein would have given up his incorrect theory anyway.)

Comment: @TimothyChow Actually, I was referring specifically to functional analysis. In other areas, particularly geometry, I would say that the subtle issues brought to the fore by mathematicians have proved to be very important — understanding global effects, for example. For whatever reason, to my knowledge, this just hasn’t been the case for analysis. I don’t know why. Back when I did this for a living, I would worry from time to time that QFT has not been made rigorous, and maybe that means there is something important we’re missing there.

Answer (score 30):

This reminds me the following anecdote. K. Friedrichs once met Heisenberg on a conference. He thanked Heisenberg for creation of quantum mechanics which benefited mathematics so much, and added:

"But mathematicians gave much in return."

Heisenberg: "What?"

Friedrichs: "For example, von Neumann explained the difference between symmetric and self-adjoint operators".

Heisenberg: "And what is the difference?"

Reference: J. Horwath, ed. A panorama of Hungarian mathematics, in the twentieth century, I, Springer 2006, Page 227; he refers to P. Lax, Func. Anal., John Willey, 2002.

Comment: This answer also demonstrates that there is a difference between asking what *mathematicians* have contributed and what *functional analysis* has contributed. (Unless one insists on defining "functional analysis" as something created solely by mathematicians.)

Comment: Heisenberg couldn’t even be bothered to use the sharp bound (ℏ/2) in *his own inequality*.

Comment: I would be very interested to know if there are actually situations where a physicist not knowing the difference between symmetric and self-adjoint could go astray.

Comment: @Kostya_I: I agree, this would be interesting. But difficult to find. Good physicists usually have very strong intuition which guards them from mistakes, and as the same time look down at mathematical niceties.

Answer (score 17):

As jjcale mentions in a comment, the index of a Fredholm operator is very important in physics. One way to define the Chern number of a topological insulator is in terms of the index of a Fredholm operator, as explained in [1].

There is also the concept of an index of a pair of projections.  This is seen a lot recently in physics papers, for example in [2].  That paper uses as a reference on the index of certain pairs of projections a paper in the Journal of Functional Analysis [3].

For physics published this year, see [4].  That paper discusses trace class operators and cites a text in functional analysis.

[1] Bellissard, Jean, Andreas van Elst, and Hermann Schulz‐Baldes. "The noncommutative geometry of the quantum Hall effect." Journal of Mathematical Physics 35.10 (1994): 5373-5451.

[2] Akagi, Yutaka, Hosho Katsura, and Tohru Koma. "A New Numerical Method for Topological Insulators with Strong Disorder." Journal of the Physical Society of Japan 86.12 (2017): 123710.

[3] Avron, J., Ruth Seiler, and Barry Simon. "The index of a pair of projections." Journal of Functional Analysis 120.1 (1994): 220-237.

[4] Zhi Li and Roger S. K. Mong, "A Local formula for the 
Z_2 invariant of topological insulators" Phys. Rev. B 100, 205101 – Published 4 November 2019.

Comment: I think this is the best answer yet.

Answer (score 12):

It is probably dangerous to answer without reading Landsman’s whole paper (and the question seems likely to be closed as “opinion-based”), but I’ll record my first reaction as much like [lcv](//mathoverflow.net/questions/348126/any-real-contribution-of-functional-analysis-to-quantum-theory-as-a-branch-of-ph#comment871820_348126)’s (<sup>a</sup>), namely, it sounds a little bit strawman-ish to separate the two and then pit one (FA) against the other (QM).

Footnotes (by Born) on pp. 583, 585 of the famous [1926 Dreimännerarbeit](//doi.org/10.1007/BF01379806) (see commented [translation](//archive.org/details/SourcesOfQuantumMechanics) pp. 351, 352) immediately identified [Hilbert’s work on linear operators](//archive.org/details/grundzugeallg00hilbrich) as the correct framework for QM, and are a literal blueprint for its extension to unbounded operators by von Neumann. If this, and Weyl’s group reformulation of $[P,Q]=I$, are not contributions of functional analysis, then I don’t know what could be!

Consider also that, as far as could be determined at [this question](//mathoverflow.net/questions/313967/reference-request-oldest-linear-algebra-books-with-exercises), the first two times our very *phrase* “linear algebra” (I don’t mean the *thing*) appears in the literature are (<sup>b,c</sup>)

1. In Hermann Weyl’s [1919 book](//archive.org/details/raumzeitmateriev00weyl/page/20) on general relativity; the phrase didn’t catch on then.
2. In Hermann Weyl’s [1928 book](//books.google.com/books?id=-VReAAAAIAAJ&q=%22lineare+Algebra%22) on quantum mechanics: ***then*** it caught on.

So QM and FA *both* played a role in establishing the other as a field of study.

---

<sup>a. Which I would qualify to: FA (some say linear algebra) “is essentially the same thing” as *those parts of QM we understand*.</sup>

<sup>b. The phrase also appears, just once fleetingly, in Courant and Hilbert’s [1924 book](//books.google.com/books?id=ikOHBwAAQBAJ&ots=V1OHN8hXMp&pg=PA100&dq=%22Verallgemeinerung+des+Problems+der+linearen+Algebra%22), of which H. Hameka writes in his nice informed [account](//books.google.com/books/?id=wtYcXH5OAS4C), p. 11: “by a fortunate coincidence, linear algebra was the subject of the first chapter in the newly published book *Methods of Mathematical Physics* by Courant and Hilbert.” Born and Jordan cited it in 1925 ([translation](//archive.org/details/SourcesOfQuantumMechanics) p. 279); like Landsman, I think the idea that physicists needed no one’s help came largely from *Dirac*’s failure to cite almost anyone.</sup>

<sup>c. Correction: I have since found the expression defined in Hellinger-Toeplitz ([1910](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002263432), p. 292): “diejenigen Partien der Algebra, die man etwa unter dem Sammelnamen einer *linearen Algebra* vereinigen könnte: bilineare Formen (Rangverhältnisse), Trägheitsgesetz der quadratischen Formen, Formenscharen (Elementarteilertheorie von Weierstraß, Kronecker, Frobenius usw.).” There remains that it only caught on after 1928. (The *Dreimännerarbeit* cites Hellinger along with Hilbert; Hellinger and Toeplitz were Born’s classmates, and after 1904 all 3 and Courant reunited in Göttingen as the “[group from Breslau](//books.google.com/books?id=7gYAAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA3)”.)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that the fissures between (sub-)disciplines are somewhat more complex than the simple functional analysis vs. quantum theory dichotomy that Landsman emphasizes.

The study of foundational questions in physics is pursued by a comparatively small group of researchers. After all, physics has to deal with observations of the real world, and the real world is messy, dirty, and usually much more complicated than those few idealizations we are able to treat with anything approaching mathematical rigor. That is not to say that it's not important to maintain and develop the contact with the foundations; but it lies in the nature of the subject that most questions asked in physics are not foundational ones.

I am not an expert in these foundational questions, but from what I have seen, physicists who are can't be accused of not paying attention to the relevant mathematical literature. And I can't help sensing an undertone in what superficially sounds like "quantum theorists aren't paying attention to functional analysis" of "mainstream physicists aren't paying attention to their colleagues working on the foundations of quantum theory."

While it may well be valid, I think this sentiment disregards the many ways functional analysis has permeated physicists' frame of mind in the course of almost a century. A physicist's intuition about quantum theory is a linear algebra intuition. It is communicated to students from the very beginning. Homage is paid to Hilbert by even calling things "Hilbert spaces" that aren't. Though it isn't usually required by the curriculum, a good advisor will urge physics students to take courses in functional analysis if there is an opportunity. Hearing the "aaah!" from a student first realizing that the solutions of a Schr\"odinger equation can be organized into a vector space is memorable. There can be no question that learning this language, even at a fairly crude level, has been instrumental in better understanding quantum systems, even in very applied settings.

On the other hand, important new developments in functional analysis do find their way into the attention of physicists - and this goes beyond the focus on foundational questions. An example are free random variables, connected to elementary particle theory [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9411021.pdf), which also led to several further explorations in the aftermath.  Granted, this didn't end up in a wholesale revolution, but it's another one of those puzzle pieces that give us an additional way to think about and understand elementary particle physics.

Answer (score 7):

The Birman-Schwinger principle bounds the number of eigenvalues of a Schrödinger operator below certain level (in terms of an integral operator involving the potential and the resolvent of the Laplacian).

This has been used in many "real physics" articles, e. g. "Bound for the Kinetic Energy of Fermions Which Proves the Stability of Matter" by Lieb and Thirring.

On might argue that Birman-Schwinger principle does not constitute a very deep application of functional analysis, which is probably true, but nevertheless even its general rigorous formulation (and, of course, proof) requires some FA.